# What does it mean that from version 1.21 the go command will no longer try to maintain compatibility with older versions of GO?

Tags: go

One of the points from the [mod documentation](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go) says the following for go 1.21:

> The go command no longer attempts to maintain compatibility with the
> previous older version of Go.

I'm not entirely clear on what this means? Does this mean that if I write in the go.mod file, for example, go 1.21 and I have a 1.22 version of the toolchain, it will not treat FOR loops "in the old way" even though I specified 1.21, but in the new way defined in go 1.22?

Is that what they wanted to say or something else?

Comment: The go command used to maintain full backwards compatibility. As the doc states, this is no longer the case. The statement you quote is simple a matter of fact, there’s nothing else to infer from it.

Comment: @JimB Is there any example currently for that (that go command doesn't maintain full backward compatibility)?

Comment: While the answer below may not be worded quite right, it is correct about the example; the go1.22 change in for-range loop behavior was a breaking change.

Comment: @JimB Agree, but that's more related to go directive and behavior of language, not about go cli command. Btw, I also tried to find some additional information in Go 1.21 official release note and could not find anything about it. Strange

Comment: @JimB I thinks its more about general behavior of golang toolchain (go command) where older versions of Go (< Go 1.21) in most cases were able to build newer golang code (for example Go 1.15 toolchain would try and in most cases be able to build 1.19 code). However, since Go 1.21, golang toolchain would not even try to build code from newer versions.

Comment: By the "go cli", assume that implies the compiler too, so if `GOEXPERIMENT=rangefunc` becomes the default it would be a breaking compiler change. There doesn't actually need to be an example, the fact that we can now have breaking changes because we can control the rollout via the go.mod directives is something that exists.

Comment: @JimB Totally agree, it's just strange the way they wrote (described) it

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `go` directive specifies how variables declared in a for loop with range clause are handled, not the version of the Go tool chain. If the value of the `go` directive is `1.21` or earlier, then the "old way" is used. This does not change when upgrading the tool chain to Go 1.22 or later.

The change in Go 1.22 is not backwards compatible. Although most code will work as is with the "new way", there is code that breaks with the change.

The quote from the documentation is saying that these backward incompatible changes are allowed starting with `go` directive `1.21`.  Prior to this version, all changes to the language were backwards compatible.

Comment: "... not the version of the Go tool chain.". Well yes, but as I know it does not specifies the version of toolchain (compiler) but it does specifies the version of language specification. Can you give me a little bit better explanation about it amend your first paragraph?

Comment: The [docs](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go) state "The go directive sets the minimum version of Go required to use this module." and "The go directive is an input into selecting which Go toolchain to run". Your answer appears to contradict this ("not the version of the Go tool chain"). I suspect that [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57001) would answer OP's question - specifically "As part of this change, older Go toolchains would refuse to try to build newer Go code".